# Refreshing auto-compiled code in iis 7?

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis-7

I'm debugging som asp.net code on a asp-classic site. The layout is sporadic and chaotic - .aspx and .aspx.cs files are in the root directory of the site, some in the app-code folder, but not the relevant file).

My problem is that i need to implement the corrections to the .aspx.cs file. Replacing the file does nothing, and i thought i could just "recycle" the application pool in the IIS manager, but no cigar. The server still loads the same buggy code.

So: How do i go about clearing the auto-compiled binary for this code, and implementing the corrections?

Thanks a bunch :)

Comment: usually just by touching the .config file forces a recompile. is that not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A full clean up for ASP.NET involves deleting all the temporary binaries

By default they are in ( depending on 32/64 bit and framework version )

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files

I also recommend that you change the temporary folder in the machine scope web.config

Answer (score 2):

If the site is pre-compiled, changing the aspx.cs file won't do a thing. You'll have to recompile the ASP.NET web application/web site project and copy the output .dll to the bin folder.

Comment: I wish it was, but it's not. Is it called auto-compiled or dynamically compiled or something along those lines?

Comment: Code in `.aspx` files will be automatically compiled (if not pre-compiled) the first time the page is accessed. Code in `.aspx.cs` files are compiled before deployment into a .dll, and don't even need to be deployed to the server. Code in the `App_Code` folder, however, will be recompiled after it's changed.